# Issue in create and write in a text file using c#

Tags: c#, file

I try to create a text file and write some data to it. I am using the following code:

```
public void AddNews(string path,string News_Title,string New_Desc)
{
    FileStream fs = null;
    string fileloc = path + News_Title+".txt";
    if (!File.Exists(fileloc))
    {
        using (fs = new FileStream(fileloc,FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write))
        {               
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileloc))
            {
                sw.Write(New_Desc);           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got this exception in stream writer:

```
The process cannot access the file '..............\Pro\Content\News\AllNews\Par.txt'
because it is being used by another process.
```

Text file is created, but I can't write to it.

Comment: Why don't you use File.WriteAllText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply do this:

```
public void AddNews(string path, string News_Title, string New_Desc)
{
    string fileloc = Path.Combine(path, News_Title+".txt");
    if (!File.Exists(fileloc)) {
        File.WriteAllText(fileloc, New_Desc);           
    }
}
```

Note that I use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a better way to create paths, and [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a simple way of creating a file and writing something to it. As MSDN says:

> If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

so we first check if the file already exists, as you did. If you want to overwrite its contents, just don't check and write directly.

Answer (score 2):

When you create your `StreamWriter` object, you're specifying the same file that you already opened as a `FileStream`.

Use the [constructor overload of `StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that accepts your `FileStream` object, instead of specifying the file again, like this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that the file is open or in use. Consider checking if the file is open before writing to it:

```
public bool IsFileOpen(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;

    try
    {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        // Is Open
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }

    //Not Open
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
{
  tw.WriteLine("The next line!");
}
```